# React Native: Is there an existing NPM package for this time bar graph?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm

Just wondering if there is an existing npm package similar to this time graph? Basically I need to show the datas in purple, all in between in yellow.

[image: Image of graph here]

Answer (score 0):

I've used [React-Highcharts](https://github.com/kirjs/react-highcharts), which is simple to integrate with React. That being said, [D3.js](https://d3js.org/) would probably have a chart closer to what you are looking for, but it's not necessarily made for React and it can be a little overwhelmingly complicated at first. [ReactD3](http://www.reactd3.org/) may have fewer options than vanilla D3.js, but it still has a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Victory Charts? You may be able to leverage their [grouped bar chart](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/gallery/stacked-grouped-bars/) functionality to do something similar.